# How to distribute Microsoft Office addin?

Tags: vba, visual-studio, ms-office, powerpoint, office-addins

I have developed a `PowerPoint addin` using **Visual Studio**. I need to share it with others. How can I share this addin to let others to use it?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Advanced Installer product to create your MSI installer:

http://www.advancedinstaller.com/

Comment: Predefined project templates for Office Add-ins http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/addins-tab.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to share de source code with others, so they can edit the code, you should use Team Foundation Server or Github.

If you just want to distribute the addin, so others can reference and use it in their code the best way would be to create a nuget package

If you want distribut the builded package to install it on different computers you could use dropbox

Comment: No, I just want to share a file (i.e. a `.msi` file, etc) to let others to use my addin. What is that file? How can I build this file?

Comment: a .msi file is basically an "installer" a.k.a. "setup" or "installer setup". You can create such installers with a Visual Studio Extension from Visual Studio Galler called "Visual Studio Installer Projects"    [https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9)

Answer (score 0):

Try ClickOnce or MSI installer - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx